# Merge numpy array to single int

Tags: python, numpy

How can a numpy array like this:

`[10, 22, 37, 45]`

be converted to a single int32 number like this:

`10223745`

Comment: `sum(arr.astype(str))`?

Comment: @Arandomcoder, which concatenation do you have in mind?  Array, list, string?

Comment: Are you really dealing with an array? or is this just a list of numbers?  Are the numbers all 2 digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could work:

```py
>>> int(''.join(map(str, [10, 22, 37, 45])))
10223745
```

Basically you use `map(str, ...)` to convert that array of integers to string, then `''.join` to concatenate each of those strings, and finally `int` to convert the whole thing to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ""
for i in num_arr:
      s += str(i)

print(int(i))
```