# Merge numpy array to single int with 2 digits for every number

Tags: python, numpy

How can a numpy array like this:

`[1, 2, 37, 0]`

be converted to a single int number like this:

`01023700`

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/65293222/1139541 'blacksite' solved a similar problem but in the problem presented above, every number should be presented with 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try format string (available from Python 3.6):

```
arr =[1, 2, 37, 0]
''.join(f'{x:02d}' for x in arr)

# '01023700'
```